# Plotting similar values on a shared index with Nans

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data in the format of (x, y, class) like the following:

```
data = [(1, 2, 'A'), (2, 3, 'A'), (3, 4, 'A'), (4, 5, 'A'), (5, 6, 'A'), (1, 4, 'B'), (2, 5, 'B'), (3, 6, 'B'), (4, 7, 'B'), (5, 8, 'B'), (1, 3, 'C'), (2, 4, 'C'), (3.1, 5, 'C'), (4.1, 6, 'C'), (5.1, 7, 'C')]
```

And I would like to plot it using `pandas`. If one uses the commands:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y', 'c'])
df.pivot(index = 'x', columns = 'c', values = 'y').plot()
plt.show()
```

The output is as follows

[image: Broken plot]

If instead we drop class C using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y', 'c'])
df[df['c'].isin(['A', 'B'])].pivot(index = 'x', columns = 'c', values = 'y').plot()
plt.show()
```

The output is

[image: fixed plot]

This is straightforward: because class C has some different `x` values, we end up with some `nan` results in the values columns which means pandas cannot plot the data.

I could use `interpolate` to fill in the missing values, as my data is not incredibly large, but the scale of my data is sufficiently large that it would make more sense to just plot class `'C'` on top of the plot with the other two, meaning it needs to

1. Be added to the legend
2. Appear in its entirety on the plot

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `seaborn` is straightforward with [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='c')
```

The other option with pandas is with `groupby`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for _label, _dfg in df.groupby('c'):
    _dfg.plot(x='x',y='y', ax=ax, label=_label)
```